# Magento - different record on category and sub category page

Tags: magento, categories, product

I have 2 category level (top level & sub category). On the top category page i need to show all the sub category with few of the sub category products for each sub categories. Also need to show some other details on the top level category page.

On the sub category page, need to show the sub category products.

As we have one template page for category and sub category product page.

How this can be handled.

Comment: I think you have two ways. Stick with original template, check for the category parent and if blank display top level category view and if not sub-category. The second way is to write a module but it can't be explained in two words.

Answer (score 1):

```
$currCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

/**
 * get sub categories of current category
 */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                   ->getCategories($currCat->getEntityId());

/** 
 * only showing active sub categories
 */
foreach($collection as $cat) {
    if($cat->getIsActive()) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                         ->load($cat->getEntityId());

        $prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                               ->addCategoryFilter($category);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')
             ->addVisibleFilterToCollection($prodCollection);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')
             ->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($prodCollection);

        ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
           <?php echo $category->getName() ?>
        </a> (<?php echo $prodCollection->count() ?>)<br/>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Source: [Get Sub Categories & Product Count](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-sub-categories-and-product-count/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link is helpfull for displaying subcategories.
http://fishpig.co.uk/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/

And for the Products you can see if the use as anchor works for you or you try
http://oggettoweb.com/blog/news/magento-extension-product-blocks/
or you modify your template to pull some products with certain attributes